# Is it possible to start a process on IPAD 2 from java script?

Tags: javascript, ios

Is it possible to start a process on an IPAD 2 from a web application?
I would like to create platform independent code (possibly using Java Script) and be able to start platform dependent code from withing it. What should I be reasearching to learn how to do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Not directly no. The web browser is pretty much a sandbox. However another application can register a URL handler and the browser can call out to that URL.

Comment: have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: Just not sure where to look.  The documentation is so massive. Can you send me a link to the documentaiton on this?